# MariaDB character set and collation on windows vs freeBSD

Tags: mysql, windows, mariadb, freebsd

I'm having some trouble tracking down why my windows development installation of MariaDB doesn't match my FreeBSD installation.  Here's some outputs from my test db on freeBSD:

```
MariaDB [www]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1             |
| character_set_connection | latin1             |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | latin1             |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [www]> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM items;
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field       | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id          | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| description | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [www]> select description from items where id=15;
+------------------------+
| description            |
+------------------------+
| 15 kΩ  1/8W 1%  (smd) |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here's the equivalent on windows:

```
MariaDB [www]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1             |
| character_set_connection | latin1             |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | latin1             |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
MariaDB [www]> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM items;
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field       | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id          | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| description | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [www]> select description from items where id=15;
+------------------------+
| description            |
+------------------------+
| 15 k╬⌐  1/8W 1%  (smd) |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So my question is, what am i missing in terms of settings comparisons that could be the source of the mangled character (Ω) on windows and what does it need to be changed to in order to get the same characters that are on my FreeBSD server.  FreeBSD installation is slightly newer 10.1.23-MariaDB FreeBSD Ports vs 10.1.19-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution.

Comment: are you using the same terminal, does the client support utf8 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem #1:** Use utf8 (or utf8mb4) throughout.  `latin1` has no `Ω`.  You were lucky to see it at all on either system.  See "Best practice" in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

**Problem #2:** On Windows, `cmd` does not necessarily default to supporting UTF-8.  The command "chcp" controls the "code page". `chcp 65001` provides UTF-8, but it needs a special charset installed, too.  To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console .

**Check:**  To see if the data is stored correctly (after changing to utf8mb4 throughout), `SELECT HEX(...) ...` to see if you get `CEA9` for the Omega.  If you get `C38EC2A9`, you have "double encoding".  Other Greek letters will be `CExx` or `CFxx` when encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Seems, on Windows, there is no way to set the default character set and collation (at least for MariaDB).   Just be sure to set these properties in your CREATE DATABASE statements.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel - Not only must one worry about the Column's charset and collation (and Table's and Database's), but one must worry about telling MySQL what charset is being used by the _client_.

Comment: My fix was this:```set global collation_database  = utf8mb4_general_ci;
set global collation_server  = utf8mb4_general_ci;
set global character_set_server = utf8mb4;```